# Fourier transform of $f[n]$ and $f[-n]$

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Hi I am just wondering,

If I have a signal $f[n]\in \mathbb{C}^L$, i.e. $f$ is $L$-periodic, i can also define $h[n]=f[-n]$.

Is it true that the Fourier transform of $f$, say $\hat{F}$, and the Fourier tranform of $h$, say $\hat{H}$ is related by the equation below?

$$|\hat{F}[k]|=|\hat{H}[k]|$$

Any advice/suggestion is welcome!

Comment: "Fourier transform" usually refers to the [continuous Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). Am I right in thinking that you wanted to ask about the discrete Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general.

Consider $f(x) = e^{ix}$ which is $2\pi$-periodic. Define $g(x) = f(-x)$ which is also $2\pi$-periodic.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\widehat f(k)&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{ix}e^{-ikx} \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{e(1 - k)x} \, dx \\
&= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } k = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

but then
\begin{align*}
\widehat g(k) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(-x) e^{-ikx} \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-ix}e^{-ikx} \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i(k + 1)x} \, dx \\
&= \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } k = -1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

So in this case, we see $\vert \widehat f(k) \vert \neq \vert \widehat g(k) \vert$ for all $k$.

However, if $f$ is real, then the [reality condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Basic_properties), $\widehat g(k) = \overline{\widehat f(k)}$ forces the result to hold.

---

**Lemma**: If $f$ is real and even, then $\widehat f$ is real and even.

**Proof**: Observe that
\begin{align*}
\widehat f(-k) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-i(-k)x} \, dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ik(-x)} \, dx = -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{-2\pi} f(-u) e^{-iku} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(u)e^{-iku} \, du = \widehat f(k)
\end{align*}
and so $\widehat f$ is even.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
\widehat f(k) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-ikx} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \big[\cos(-kx) + i \sin(-kx) \big] \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos (kx) \, dx - \frac{i}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \sin(kx) \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \cos (kx) \, dx + 0
\end{align*}
The latter part is zero since $f(x) \sin (kx)$ is odd about the center, and we can switch from $0 \to 2\pi$ to $-\pi \to \pi$ because of translation invariance.

**Lemma**: If $f$ is real and odd, then $\widehat f$ is pure imaginary and odd.

**Proof**: Similar as above.

**Theorem**: Setting $g(x) = f(-x)$, we get $\widehat g = \overline{\widehat f}$.

**Proof**: Write $f$ as the sum of an even function and an odd function: $f = f_e + f_o$. Then $\widehat f = \widehat f_e + \widehat f_o$.

Observe that $g(x) = f(-x) = f_e(-x) + f_o(-x) = f_e(x) - f_o(x)$, hence $\widehat g = \widehat f_e - \widehat f_o = \overline{\widehat f}$.

Comment: Given that the question had the tag (discrete-mathematics) until a few days ago, and given the notation ($\mathbb C^L$ and the square brackets), I think OP was asking about the discrete transform? Although perhaps analogous results will hold there.

Comment: I made it a community wiki. If anyone knows of the analogous result, feel free to add it here.

Comment: @dustin, It's a community wiki, so if you think you can salvage it, feel free to make any changes!